# Creating a loop to suggest username+number - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've been trying to create a procedure to implement in user creation. The procedure is meant to see if the username is already taken, in which case it has to print an alternative username. The alternate needs to be constructed from the username+lowest number that is not already taken.

For example, if I tried "Ofek" and both "Ofek" and "Ofek1" are taken, I should receive "Ofek2".

So far this is what I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SuggestUsername]
    @username varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name varchar(10)

    IF @username IN (SELECT User_Name FROM Players WHERE User_Name = @username)
        WHILE (@name IN (SELECT User_Name FROM Players WHERE User_Name = @username))
            SET @name = (CONCAT(@username, +1))
            PRINT (CONCAT('Username already taken. Please choose a different one, or use: ', @name))
END
```

For some reason, `@name` comes up as empty whenever I tried running it. Is there a better way to do it? if not, what's wrong with my current code?

Thanks in advance!

*edit*
I've decided to give up this idea and try to implement it differently (with a count of how many times @username already appears as the additional number). Thanks for all who tried to help.

Comment: What if the suggested name ends with a number?

Comment: And what if the passed in user name is already 10 characters so no room to append a number? TBH 10 characters seems extremely short as a maximum length for user name. And probably it should support `nvarchar` characters to allow people with non latin characters in their name to use their own names

Comment: 1. It should always end with a number. Why would that be a problem?
2. It's just a sample for testing purposes. I will eventually increase the length.

Comment: `declare @name varchar(10)` defaults to `null` which, hopefully, will never be found in `select User_Name from Players where User_Name=@username`.

Comment: That's true, but if the loop was working as it should, it shouldn't be null. The value should be set as @username+1/2/3 etc. Until it no longer comes up in (select user_name)

Comment: you still haven't answered Gordon's question satisfactorily. If someone tries to register Ofek1992 and that is already taken should it suggest Ofek1993 or Ofek19921?

Comment: 1993. I honestly didn't take that into account in my code.

Comment: Is it wise or secure to make this sort of suggestion? Think carefully about this!

Comment: I wouldn't implement this in a real DB, but this is for a class - so no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that this is just `"for a class"` in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172083/creating-a-loop-to-suggest-usernamenumber-sql-server#comment108218654_61172083) and I have time to spend because of COVID, here is a trick.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) N
  FROM (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) T(A) CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) TT(B) CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) TTT(C) CROSS JOIN
       (VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) TTTT(D);
       -- 6561 number

CREATE TABLE Users
(
  UserName VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
);

INSERT Users VALUES
('Ofek'), ('Ofek1');


CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @UserName VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN

  WITH CTE(N, UN) AS
  (
    SELECT 0, @UserName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N, CONCAT(@UserName, N)
    FROM MyView
  )
  INSERT Users(UserName)
  SELECT TOP 1 UN
  FROM CTE
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE UserName = UN)
  ORDER BY N;
END

EXEC MyProc 'Ofek';

SELECT * FROM Users;
```

You can see how it's working on a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db07903c69e8cc90b45d5b86e8f8f6de)

---

I won't recommend this as a real solution or a way to work with on a real database, instead you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint or using `EXISTS()` to notify the user if the name is already taken without suggesting.